# CSS text-align: center; is not centering things

Tags: css, text-align

I have the following html:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul id="menu-utility-navigation" class="links clearfix">
        <li class="menu-685 menu-site_map first">Site Map
        </li>
        <li class="menu-686 menu-privacy_policy">Privacy Policy
        </li>
        <li class="menu-687 menu-terms___conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions
        </li>
        <li class="menu-688 menu-contact_us last">Contact Us
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div#footer {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;
}
```

I threw in the font-size bit just to see if the style was working (Firebug reports it is working but I wanted to see).  It is working.  But the text is not centered in the footer in Firefox or in Safari (have yet to check it in IE).

I tried with and without margin: 0 auto; and with and without text-align: center; no combo of those things worked.

Here is output from Firebug:

```
div#footer {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;
}

Inherited fromdiv#page
#skip-to-nav, #page {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

Inherited frombody.html
body {
    color: #666666;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Help?

Comment: A little advice: browsers apply styles from right to left, so you div#footer is parsed two times when the page is load, an unnecessary performance penalty (a small one anyway) which you can avoid because you can only have one #footer per page. (Sorry for my English).

Comment: Thanks Tae!  I didn't know that.  Beginner with CSS basically.

Comment: Here's an article that goes into detail on when to use `margin:auto;` and `text-align:center;` for centering elements: https://blog.terresquall.com/2021/07/why-doesnt-text-align-center-work-a-primer-on-block-and-inline-elements-in-html-css/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I assume you want all the items next to each other, and the whole thing to be centered horizontally.

`li` elements are `display: block` by default, taking up all the horizontal space.

Add

```
div#footer ul li { display: inline }
```

once you've done that, you probably want to get rid of the list's bullets:

```
div#footer ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px }
```

Comment: Yes, the ul was displaying horizontally already.  I wanted it to that navigation to be centered in the footer.  I think the ul was inheriting the width of the footer div.  I set the width of the ul and it centered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

To make a inline-block element align center horizontally in its parent, add `text-align:center` to its parent.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks! 

I had applied `text-align: center` to the text elements but not to the containing `div`

Comment: that did the job. Applying `text-align: center` to the parent worked.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the text within the list items to be centred, try:

```
ul#menu-utility-navigation {
  width: 100%;
}

ul#menu-utility-navigation li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `display: block;` `margin: auto;`
it will center the div

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider adding a short snippet of code to illustrate your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex-grow: 1`. The default value is `0` and it will cause the `text-align: center` looks like `left`.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
  e.Row.Cells["cell no "].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

But `'css text-align = center '` didn't worked for me

hope it will help you

Answer (score -4):

I don't Know you use any Bootstrap version but the useful helper class for centering and block an element in center it is `.center-block` because this class contain `margin` and `display` CSS properties but the `.text-center` class only contain the `text-align` property

[Bootstrap Helper Class center-block](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)

Comment: he asked for help with css properties. your recommendation is for using bootstrap to abstract away css, and so it is therefore off-topic.